# Gathering class and method code coverage data using TFS APIs

Tags: code-coverage

Is there any way I can read code coverage information using TFS APIs?
I'm more interested in reading class level and method level coverage;

Using CoverageAnalysisManager, we were able to get Assembly level coverage with details on BlocksCovered etc.

Thanks,
Vijaya

Answer (score 0):

See the links below to get started

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.coverage.analysis.coverageinfo.aspx
2. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phuene/archive/2009/12/01/programmatic-coverage-analysis-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx